# Relative DIV width and height

Tags: html, css, image, svg, width

I want to have a DIV, which is maximum 90% height OR 90% width. I just want to fit a picture as a background into the DIV and the full svg-image should be visible. On mobile as well as on the desktop.

**CSS:**

```
.camera {
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(../img/svg-bild.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

ps: I used google but can't find something useful. I know somewhere out there it would be, but I have to less time to search 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the background image not to be cropped and always fit in the container, you can use `background-size: contain;` *([more info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values))*.

You also need to change the `max-width/max-height` to `height/width` otherwise your element will have 0 height/width as it doesn't contain anything :

```
.camera {
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(../img/svg-bild.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:contain; /** add this **/
    height: 90%;  /** change this **/
    width: 90%;  /** change this **/
}
```

Comment: This one woked verry well :) Thanks man! I can't upvote you, because i have a to low rank... I will do it when i can ;)¨

Comment: @Patrick glad I could help. If your issue is solved please don't add 'closed' to the title of your question just click on the tick next to the asnwser that soved your issue.

Comment: Doesn't quite fill the requirements of the question at hand. There is no guarantee that the image will be square, so the container won't hold the dimensions of the image - will simply create a square block. That said, without having dimensions to play with, this is as good as it will get. Perhaps if the OP had given more info on what is being used (jQuery, CSS and HTML for sure) like PHP or anything similar, you could pre-load sizes to do what was requested.

Comment: @MrMarlow This won't necesseraly create a square block. the dimesions of the block will depend on the dimesions of the relatively positioned parent. The background-size property will garantee that the image isn't cropped though, independent on the the block/image size/aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `background-size:cover` or `background-size:contain`

```
.camera {
background-size:cover;/*background-size:contain;*/
position:absolute;
background-image: url(../img/svg-bild.svg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
max-height: 90%;
max-width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that the image doesn't apear and the DIV has a width and height of 0x0px...

Comment: @Patrick change `max-height` to `min-height` or just `height` and do this for the width also

Comment: `background-size:cover` will crop the image.

Comment: @web-tiki ok will do it like you said `background-size: contain;`

Comment: @Patrick try what i said and change `background-size:cover` to `background-size:contain` if you want it un cropped

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/mijadi/2/)**

```
.camera {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../img/svg-bild.svg) 50% / cover;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    /*margin:auto;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; /* UNCOMMENT TO CENTER */
}
```